# Artifacts in rendered geometry

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender so I started to watch tutorials. Recently i have been doing tunnel tutorial. But i have problem with rendering.
[image]

As you can see on the picture above there is a problem with tracks and walls. As for the walls i dont know if it is a issue with textures or rendering. But on the rails there is no textures, yet there is a problem. I tried to render only rails and lights and i still get same result. I am rendering on Blender render.
I am working on default Blender settings, so maybe i need to adjust settings to my computer.
Best regards

Comment: It looks like z-fighting, which is caused by overlapping faces.  Are there two sets of tracks in the same place?

Comment: You were right with tracks. I messed up with mirror modifier. I need to model tracks once again. But adding textures is black magic for me. I cannot follow tutorial casue i don't have access to same texures and i need to use lower res textures. Here is link for my blender file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0kehJY37c4wLVJBQnpfOWprbHM&authuser=0 Cheers